# I need to create an excel formula to calculate vacation time with maximum accrual of 240hours

Tags: excel

I need to create an excel formula to calculate vacation time with a maximum accrual of 240hours. Right now my formula just calculates what is carried over from last month, earned this month and then used this month. Is there a way to make it so it only calculates up to 240 hours per month. Here is my current formula =SUM(+E13,+C14,-D14)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it would be:

```
=MIN(240, E13 + C14 - D14)
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps:

```
=MIN(240,E13+C14-D14)
```